# rails rspec reflect_on_association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am following [this book](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_eight) and working on the order model validation.

This is my `order_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Order, type: :model do
  let(:order) { FactoryGirl.build :order }
  subject { :order }

  it { should respond_to(:total) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }

  it { should validate_presence_of :user_id }
  it { should validate_presence_of :total}
  it { should validate_numericality_of(:total).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(0) }

  it { should belong_to :user }


  it { should have_many(:placements) }
  it { should have_many(:products).through(:placements) }

end
```

My factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order do
    user
    total "9.99"
  end
end
```

`order.rb`

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :total, presence: true,
                      numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  validates :user_id, presence: true

  has_many :placements
  has_many :products, through: :placements
end
```

`placement.rb`:

```
class Placement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :placements
  belongs_to :product, inverse_of: :placements
end
```

Users model `user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  validates :auth_token, uniqueness: true

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
    :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_create :generate_authentication_token!
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy

  def generate_authentication_token!
    begin
      self.auth_token = Devise.friendly_token
    end while self.class.exists?(auth_token: auth_token)
  end

  # validate :password_must_match
  # def password_must_match
  #   errors.add(:password, "doesn't match confirmation") if password != password_confirmation
  # end

end
```

Now I got this error:

```
  1) Order should have many placements
     Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:placements) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `reflect_on_association' for Symbol:Class
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Order should require total to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :total}

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `total=' for :order:Symbol
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Order should respond to #total
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:total) }
       expected :order to respond to :total
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Order should respond to #user_id
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
       expected :order to respond to :user_id
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Order should only allow numbers for total which are greater than or equal to 0
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_numericality_of(:total).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(0) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `total=' for :order:Symbol
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Order should require user_id to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :user_id }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user_id=' for :order:Symbol
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Order should belong to user
     Failure/Error: it { should belong_to :user }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `reflect_on_association' for Symbol:Class
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Order should have many products through placements
     Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:products).through(:placements) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `reflect_on_association' for Symbol:Class
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877751/shoulda-with-rspec-gem-returning-undefined-method-reflect-on-association-for) (possible duplicate), but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Are there pending migrations in your test environment? Test with `ENV=test rails db:migrate:status` or just run them with `ENV=test rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `subject` is a symbol `subject { :order }`. I think you did mean `subject { order }`

Comment: why? i dont have any function or local var named order

Comment: `let(:order) { FactoryGirl.build :order }` creates a memoized helper method with the name `order` . The same is true for `subject` . You'r version says that subject returns the symbol `order`, but you want to achive is to return the return value of the method `order` created by `let`